# Is it possible to make an object that acts like a function when called in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I want to make an object that has properties but can also be called. Sort of like the toString property that returns a string that represents the object when it's used as a string.

something that works like this:

```
o = {
  prop: 2
  toFunction: function(a) {
    return a;
  }
}

o('foo'); // returns foo
o.prop; // returns 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function is an object in JavaScript so you can do:

```
var o = function(a) { return a; }
o.prop = 2;
```

and so

```
o('foo'); // returns foo
o.prop; // returns 2
```